# location of twitter.py file (python-twitter library) in Mac OS X 10.6.7 with Python 2.6.7

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I have python 2.6.7 installed in my mac (/usr/local/bin/python).
Previously, I installed python-twitter library. I follow these steps when I installed it:

1. tar -xvf python-twitter-0.8.3.tar.gz
2. cd python-twitter-0.8.3
3. python setup.py build
4. python setup.py install

But, right now, I want to modify the twitter.py file generated when I installed the module. I have tried to find it in python's site-packages directory, but I couldn't find it.

For your information, here is the PYTHONPATH:
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/oauth2-1.5.170-py2.6.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson-2.1.6-py2.6-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_twitter-0.8.2-py2.6.egg
/usr/local/lib/python26.zip
/usr/local/lib/python2.6
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/plat-mac
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-old
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/Users/*username*/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages

I have used the 'locate' command to find it in all folders, but still couldn't find it.

Anyone know where to find the twitter.py file?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are saying - does '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_twitter-0.8.3-py2.6.egg exist?

Comment: Could you tell us everything on your `PYTHONPATH`? That would be sys.path in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inside the .egg file, which is actually a zip archive.

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages-> zipinfo python_twitter-0.8.2-py2.6.egg
Archive:  python_twitter-0.8.2-py2.6.egg   60381 bytes   8 files
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx   122153 b- defN 16-Apr-11 16:57 twitter.py
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx   128307 b- defN 28-Jun-11 09:14 twitter.pyc
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx        1 b- defN 28-Jun-11 09:14 EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx    25334 b- defN 28-Jun-11 09:14 EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx       28 b- defN 28-Jun-11 09:14 EGG-INFO/requires.txt
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      397 b- defN 28-Jun-11 09:14 EGG-INFO/SOURCES.txt
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx        8 b- defN 28-Jun-11 09:14 EGG-INFO/top_level.txt
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx        1 b- defN 28-Jun-11 09:14 EGG-INFO/zip-safe
8 files, 276229 bytes uncompressed, 59457 bytes compressed:  78.5%
```

If you want to make changes, the easiest thing to do is to edit the file BEFORE you run setup.py.  In your case, just make your changes and re-run setup.py again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to edit the file Before I run the setup.py and it works! =D

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple

```
import twitter
print(twitter.__path__)
```

to find out where it is? Also, `repr(twitter)` should be something like

```
<module 'twitter' from '/path/you/want/twitter.py'>
```

You might also want to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) to set up a nice sandbox for testing your modifications before applying them system-wide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the second method works for me, but not for the first one. :)