# Error Installing Scikits.audiolab

Tags: python, macos, pip, scikits

I'm trying to install scikits.audiolab with pip.  I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212486/error-installing-scikits-audiolab-when-using-python-setup-py-egg-info), however, it looks like that user's problem was that they hadn't installed numpy.  I can replicate their trace by uninstalling numpy and running `pip install scikits.audiolab`.  The trace that I get when I have numpy is:

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: sndfile (http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) library not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
site.cfg file, in section [sndfile].

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/p8/tbdq1bmx54d68dftpx9_p6qr0000gn/T/pip-build-vuIg71/scikits.audiolab/
```

Everything I've found about this error points me to downloading scikits.audiolab from pypi and running `python setup.py install` which is apparently "statically linked to libsndfile."  But when I follow those instructions I get nearly the same error:

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: sndfile (http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) library not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
site.cfg file, in section [sndfile].
```

Running `pip -V` returns `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`

Running `python --version` returns `Python 2.7.12`

Anyone that can point me in the right direction would be a true hero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that I was missing libsndfile.  I stumbled onto [Python audiolab install, unable to install (or find) libsndfile on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999790/python-audiolab-install-unable-to-install-or-find-libsndfile-on-mac-osx) which provided fantastic directions that worked like a charm.  I also have [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) so apparently `brew install libsndfile` would have worked also.  After this I was able to install scikits.audiolab with `pip install scikits.audiolab`

Answer (score 5):

Solved the problem on Ubuntu 16.04 by installing the `libsndfile1-dev` package

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

For installing scikits.audiolab, you surely need Python 2.7

So running the following command will resolve the issue:

```bash
sudo python2.7 -m pip install scikits.audiolab
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to install this on Big Sur (though not sure it is Big Sur specific):

```
2021-10-19T10:06:54,996   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:981:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_FromStringAndSize' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
2021-10-19T10:06:54,996     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_buff, strlen(__pyx_v_buff)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 115; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,002     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_buff, strlen(__pyx_v_buff)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 115; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,008   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:1861:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_FromStringAndSize' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
2021-10-19T10:06:55,008     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_format_info.name, strlen(__pyx_v_format_info.name)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 215; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,008     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_format_info.name, strlen(__pyx_v_format_info.name)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 215; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,009     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_format_info.name, strlen(__pyx_v_format_info.name)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 227; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,032     __pyx_t_3 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 646; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,033     __pyx_t_3 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 659; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,035     __pyx_t_3 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 672; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,037     __pyx_t_3 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 685; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,039     __pyx_t_5 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_5)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 731; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:55,070   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11168:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:55,070   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11169:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,070   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11170:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,071   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11179:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:55,071   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11180:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,071   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11181:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,071   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11182:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:55,071   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11183:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,071   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11184:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,072   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11357:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:55,072   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11358:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,072   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11359:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,072   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11360:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:55,072   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11361:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,073   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11362:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:55,073   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11399:14: error: implicit declaration of function 'PyCObject_FromVoidPtr' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
2021-10-19T10:06:55,076   scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11612:25: error: implicit declaration of function 'PyNumber_Int' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
2021-10-19T10:06:55,078   fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2021-10-19T10:06:55,080   65 warnings and 20 errors generated.
2021-10-19T10:06:55,085   error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/qt@5/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.o.d" failed with exit status 1
2021-10-19T10:06:55,128   ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikits.audiolab
2021-10-19T10:06:56,870     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:981:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_FromStringAndSize' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
2021-10-19T10:06:56,870       __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_buff, strlen(__pyx_v_buff)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 115; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,876       __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_buff, strlen(__pyx_v_buff)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 115; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,882     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:1861:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'PyString_FromStringAndSize' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
2021-10-19T10:06:56,882       __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_format_info.name, strlen(__pyx_v_format_info.name)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 215; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,882       __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_format_info.name, strlen(__pyx_v_format_info.name)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 215; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,882       __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_format_info.name, strlen(__pyx_v_format_info.name)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 227; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,905       __pyx_t_3 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 646; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,907       __pyx_t_3 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 659; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,908       __pyx_t_3 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 672; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,910       __pyx_t_3 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 685; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,912       __pyx_t_5 = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(__pyx_2, ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_2), ((PyObject *)__pyx_1)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_5)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 731; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
2021-10-19T10:06:56,944     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11168:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:56,944     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11169:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,945     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11170:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,945     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11179:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:56,945     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11180:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,945     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11181:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,946     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11182:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:56,946     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11183:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,946     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11184:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,946     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11357:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:56,946     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11358:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,946     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11359:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,947     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11360:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
2021-10-19T10:06:56,947     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11361:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,947     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11362:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
2021-10-19T10:06:56,947     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11399:14: error: implicit declaration of function 'PyCObject_FromVoidPtr' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
2021-10-19T10:06:56,950     scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c:11612:25: error: implicit declaration of function 'PyNumber_Int' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
2021-10-19T10:06:56,952     fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2021-10-19T10:06:56,954     65 warnings and 20 errors generated.
2021-10-19T10:06:56,958     error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/qt@5/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/_sndfile.o.d" failed with exit status 1
2021-10-19T10:06:56,996 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dr/28w42sbj7xj4r02p4xn44kt00000gr/T/pip-install-kr7isat0/scikits-audiolab_61e03334be2948edbb0d1001e32cb290/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dr/28w42sbj7xj4r02p4xn44kt00000gr/T/pip-install-kr7isat0/scikits-audiolab_61e03334be2948edbb0d1001e32cb290/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dr/28w42sbj7xj4r02p4xn44kt00000gr/T/pip-record-umy6eo2i/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/scikits.audiolab Check the logs for full command output.
2021-10-19T10:06:56,997     raise InstallationSubprocessError(proc.returncode, command_desc)
2021-10-19T10:06:56,997 pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationSubprocessError: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dr/28w42sbj7xj4r02p4xn44kt00000gr/T/pip-install-kr7isat0/scikits-audiolab_61e03334be2948edbb0d1001e32cb290/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dr/28w42sbj7xj4r02p4xn44kt00000gr/T/pip-install-kr7isat0/scikits-audiolab_61e03334be2948edbb0d1001e32cb290/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dr/28w42sbj7xj4r02p4xn44kt00000gr/T/pip-record-umy6eo2i/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/scikits.audiolab Check the logs for full command output.
```